# flutter getting build error on linux while using dart_vlc

Tags: android, linux, windows, flutter, video

I am trying to build a crossplatform video player app, for android, windows and macos. I use flutter on linux mint. when I create a fresh flutter project with flutter create and add dart_vlc: ^0.4.0 and try to run with f5, I am getting this build error:

````
> /home/beautiful/Documents/flutter-apps/deleteme/linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/dart_vlc/core/api/api.cc:43:48:
> warning: cannot delete expression with pointer-to-'void' type 'void *'
> [-Wdelete-incomplete] clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Exception: Build process failed```

here is my `flutter doctor -v`

```[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Linux Mint 20.3 5.4.0-137-generic,
    locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at
      /home/beautiful/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (5 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/beautiful/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /home/beautiful/Templates/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /home/beautiful/Templates/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Linux Mint 20.3
      5.4.0-137-generic
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.74

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to install lvlc

sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev

flutter run